# Flip month and day in SQL Server DateTime field

Tags: sql-server

I have a portion of my data that has been parsed incorrectly (due to earlier mistakes in handling Culture) so that the month and the day should be flipped.  Is there an easy way to do this in SQL Server?  Fortunately, it is still early enough in the dataset that it is easy to locate the bad data.

*Update* I think this will work:

```
SELECT seen, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, seen,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(YEAR(seen) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
        + RIGHT('0'+CAST(DAY(seen) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + 
        + RIGHT('0'+CAST(MONTH(seen) AS VARCHAR(2)),2), 112)), seen)
FROM TermStats
WHERE seen < '2011-09-01' AND DAY(seen) <= 12
```

But I think I can do better.  All good dates are after 9/1.  (You can tell I really lucked out here... lol)

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(seen), MONTH(seen), DAY(seen)
FROM TermStats
ORDER BY YEAR(seen), MONTH(seen), DAY(seen)

2006    2   13
2011    3   9
2011    4   9
2011    5   9
2011    6   9
2011    9   3
2011    9   4
2011    9   5
2011    9   6
```

Comment: I don't understand how that's possible - you won't have been able to record any dates with a day-of-month greater than 12. Please give more information about where the data has come from - are you able to get at the *original* (correct) data again?

Comment: Can you provide an example for it?

Comment: Where is the data now? Table? Staging table? File? Is it stored as varchar?  What marks a bad row? It's easy to fix in 2 or 3 ways depending on situation

Comment: DATETIME in SQL Server.  @Jon Skeet - I don't think it is possible to get original data again, but it has only been going for a few days (September).  So I have dates like 3/9/2011, 4/9/2011, which re clearly 2011-09-03, etc.  There is one odd ball, as you wisely recognized, I have someone whose clock is set at 2006-02-13

Comment: @tofutim: So that "someone" won't have been able to add any data, presumably?

Comment: Hehehe, can life really be that simple? ;)

Comment: The new version of the client will post DateTime as a binary instead of a string (inside xml)!  doh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't do it through string manipulation. It's entirely possible that you can do it nicely in a stored procedure, but I'd *personally* (as someone with little SQL experience) write a client side tool to fix it:

- Fetch the ID and date of every row you need to fix (fetching the date/time value *as* a date/time value, *not* as a string)
- Create the *correct* date, e.g. in C# using `new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Day, dt.Month);` to flip the fields of the wrong date
- Update the database with a parameterized query - again, *not* converting the dates into strings

Basically, wherever you can, avoid conversion between text and other formats. It only leads to the kind of pain you've already discovered.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
You meant to write:
 new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);

Comment: @AndersBranderud: Given that the point is to flip the month and day, no, I wrote what I intended to write.

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry, I got confused.. I used the code for another purpose with another context.